# Query to check if the record exists in Spring Jdbc Template

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I am fairly new to spring ,I am looking to check if a certain email id exists in database or not , using Spring Jdbc Template ,I looked here but could'nt find the proper answer .I am looking something like ,`SELECT count(*) from table where email=?`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do something as below if you are using `jdbctemplate` and new version of `spring`

```
private boolean isEmailIdExists(String email) {
    String sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE email = ?";

    int count = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] { email }, Integer.class);

    return count > 0;
}
```

`queryForObject` method of `jdbcTemplate` accepts the sql query as the first parameter, second argument is an array of objects for the sql query place holders and the third argument is the expected return value from the sql query.

In this case we only have one place holder and hence I gave the second argument as `new Object[] { email }` and the result we are expecting is a count which is a Integer and hence I gave it as `Integer.class`

I kind of got this answer from https://www.mkyong.com/spring/jdbctemplate-queryforint-is-deprecated/

You can go through it if you are interested.

Comment: You don't need to count rows if you're just looking for existence. `SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1` will do less work. It will return one row early or zero rows if none matched.

Answer (score 3):

```
private boolean isEmailIdExists(String email) {

    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT FROM table WHERE email = ?)", Boolean.class, email);
}
```

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-exists/

Comment: You are very late to the party .

Comment: You need to add "1" after the inner SELECT

    `
    SELECT EXISTS(SELECT **1** FROM table WHERE email = ?)
    `